# How to read thousands of files in different folders and server localtion using multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, filereader

I need to search data in thousands of xml files across different folder and across different server locations. Once there is a match then list all those files.

```
    String[] servers = {"server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5", "server6"};
    
// number of folders can be up to 30
    String[] folders = {"folder1", "folder2", "folder3", "folder4", "folder5", "folder6", "folder7"};

        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
String envName = "env1";
        for (String server : servers) {
            for (String folder: folders) {
                String path = File.separator+File.separator + server + File.separator + "e$" + File.separator + "archive" + File.separator + envName + File.separator + "BACKUP" + File.separator + folder;
                paths.add(path);
            }
        }
```

This means 42 different locations of files(Which can be higher also). Now each of these folders can have around 2500 to 3000 xml files in them.

One I get the file, I need to search for certain text in them and list all the files having that text.

Right now I am using below code for reading the file -

```
private static void readFile(List<String> paths){
        for (String path : paths) {
            File filePath = new File(path);
            File[] filesList = filePath.listFiles();
            int numberOfThreads = 2;
            if (null != filesList) {
                Thread[] threads = new Thread[numberOfThreads];
                final int filesPerThread = filesList.length / numberOfThreads;
                final int remainingFiles = filesList.length % numberOfThreads;
                for (int t = 0; t < numberOfThreads; t++) {
                    final int thread = t;
                    threads[t] = new Thread(() -> runThread(filesList, numberOfThreads, thread, filesPerThread, remainingFiles));
                }
                for (Thread t1 : threads)
                    t1.start();

                for (Thread t2 : threads) {
                    try {
                        t2.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void runThread(File[] filesList, int numberOfThreads, int thread, int filesPerThread, int remainingFiles) {
        List<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(filesList).subList(thread * filesPerThread, (thread + 1) * filesPerThread));

        if (thread == numberOfThreads - 1 && remainingFiles > 0) {
            inFiles.addAll(Arrays.asList(filesList).subList(filesList.length - remainingFiles, filesList.length));
        }

        for (File file : inFiles) {
            resultMap.putAll(checkFileDetails(file));
        }
    }
```

This code takes around 10 mins or more depending on the number of files. Is there any other way I can us multithreading to make it faster?

Below is basic structure of all the servers and folders
[image: Below is basic structure of all the servers and folders]

**Edit**
I tried using ExecutorService also but it is taking more time as compare to code using Thread[] (mentioned above)

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            List<Future<Map<String, String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
            if (null != folder.listFiles()) {
                Map<String, String> data = new TreeMap<>();
                Callable<Map<String, String>> callable = () -> {
                    List<File> filesList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(folder.listFiles()));
                    filesList.parallelStream().forEach(file -> data.putAll(checkFileDetails(file)));
                    return data;
                };
                futures.add(pool.submit(callable));
            }
            pool.shutdown();
            for (Future<Map<String, String>> future : futures) {
                try {
                    map.putAll(future.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Usually, in order to improve the performance of your code, you first need to profile it. Have you? Your code is both network intensive and I/O intensive. The time taken to execute the code therefore also depends on the hardware, i.e. the network and the disks. By the way, have you checked the performance of method `checkFileDetails`?

Comment: So each server has seven folders with the same seven names?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, The folder structure is same on all the servers.

Comment: *t2.join();* That's a red flag - why are you doing that? Also not sure why you're not using an `ExecutorService` at bottom

Comment: @g00se I tried that also. I have edited the problem and added the code I have used. Please have a look.

Comment: *Edit I tried using ExecutorService also but it is taking more time as compare to code using Thread[]* I'm going to leave that to someone more expert in concurrency than I. I do notice, however, that you have supposedly 42 servers yet you create a fixed thread pool of 10...

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, use a lucene index